# Powershell and Outlook

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I have a problem readiing emails from an Inbox using powershell - however I can red emails from another folder (Test) without a problem. The code I have is

```
$account = "aaaa.bbb@xxxx.net"
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)

$Account = $n.Folders | ? {$_.Name -eq $account}
$f = $Account.Folders | ? {$_.Name -match "Test"}

$f.Items | ForEach {
 Do Stuff
}
```

How do I amend the code so it read the emails from the Inbox and not the folder Test. Another thing is that there's another email account attached and that to has an inbox. How do I make sure I'm looking at the Inbox for the email address specified?

Thanks in Advance

G

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar and I'm using the following (I haven't tested yet on multiple mailboxes yet but it works for my own email)

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -ComObject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$emailAddress = "..."
$recipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient($emailAddress)
$folder = $namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($recipient, $olFolders::olFolderInbox)
```